# What are the roots of the polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Suppose $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a PSD matrix. $diag(a_1,\ldots,a_n)-A$ is positve definite.
Define    $p(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \det[diag(x_1,\cdots,x_n)-A] .$
Define
$q(x) = p(x,\cdots,x,a_{k+1},\cdots,a_n),$
which is a degree-$k$ univariate polynomial.

My question: Are all the roots of polynomial $q$ positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true. Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(a_{k+1},\ldots,a_n)$ and $A=\pmatrix{P&R\\ R^T&S}$ where $S$ has the same size as $D$. Since both $A$ and $\operatorname{diag}(a_1,\ldots,a_n)-A$ are positive definite, $P$ and $D-S$ are positive definite. Now, by using Schur complement, we obtain
\begin{aligned}
q(x)
&=\det\left((xI_k\oplus D)-A\right)\\
&=\det\pmatrix{xI-P&-R\\ -R^T&D-S}\\
&=\det(D-S)\det\left(xI-P-R(D-S)^{-1}R^T\right).
\end{aligned}
Therefore $q(x)=0$ if and only if $x$ is an eigenvalue of the positive definite matrix $P+R(D-S)^{-1}R^T$. It follows that all roots of $q(x)=0$ are positive.